# Using a std::vector<char> as a variant

Tags: c++

I want a simple variant with

- minimal overhead
- that can be passed to functions written in the C language

so I decided to use a std::vector like this

```
typedef std::vector<char> SimpleVariant;
SimpleVariant data;
```

(1) store a std::string

```
for(std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        data.push_back( *it );
    }
    data.push_back('\0');
```

(2) store a double

```
data.resize(64);
std::sprintf(&data[0], "%.*g", 20, val);
```

(3) get a string

```
std::string str = std::string( m_data.begin(), m_data.end() );
```

(4) get a double

```
double dbl = boost::lexical_cast<double>(&data[0]);
```

Is this a reasonable approach given my requirements? Is there lightweight variant that I can use instead of trying to reinvent the wheel? 
I am aware of boost::variant and boost::any they are too heavyweight for my needs

Comment: I'm confused. You want to pass a std::vector to functions written in C? C and C++ are different languages. std::vector exists only in C++.

Comment: You want a lightweight variant, and you dismiss `boost::variant` and `boost::any` as too heavyweight, and you solution is to store values as strings and rely on `lexical_cast<>` to extract them?  Why not just use a structure with a type enumeration and a union?

Comment: Profile this approach against boost::any. Pick which performs best.

Comment: @Chad: std::strings can't be stored straightforwardly in a union.

Comment: Correct, but std::string can't be passed to C anyway.

Comment: really?  what about c_str() ??

Comment: Storing a floating point number as a lexical representation sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: `(2) store a double:` Stop using `sprintf`! If you need to printf to a string, use `snprintf`. Or `_snprintf`; your compiler will have at least one of those.

Comment: @krisostofa: What about calling c_str()? That's not passing a `std::string`; it's passing a `const char *`. Similar effect, but not the same thing.

Comment: `boost::variant` and `boost::any` are most probably *cheaper* than the solution you are trying to implement. They need a dynamic allocation (as your solution) but they do not need conversions from and to a string (cheaper than your solution), and they provide type safety.

Comment: Since you have to call `c_str()` to pass it into a C function (Which is one of the requirements), obviously you wouldn't hold a `std::string` in the variant type.  Once you're in the C function, you can't call `c_str()` so that has to be done before going into the C function, meaning at that point you're not passing a variant at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really given much information about how the C interface to this works. So this suggestion may not be helpful. But let's assume you have a C interface that looks like this:

```
int GetAValue(void *data, int size); //Returns the type of data stored in the data pointer. Will not write past size.
void DoSomethingWithValue(int type, void *data, int size); //Gives data to C, to do something with. Does not modify it.
void ModifyValue(int type, void *data, int size); //Gives data to C, where it modifies it.
```

I would use a boost::variant as follows:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string> MyVariant;

struct DoSomethingWithValueVisit : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  void operator()(int val)
  {
    DoSomethingWithValue(TYPE_INTEGER, &val, sizeof(int));
  }

  void operator()(double val)
  {
    DoSomethingWithValue(TYPE_DOUBLE, &val, sizeof(double));
  }

  void operator()(const std::string &val)
  {
    DoSomethingWithValue(TYPE_STRING, (void*)val.c_str(), val.size() + 1);
  }
};

struct ModifyValueVisit : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  void operator()(int &val)
  {
    ModifyValue(TYPE_INTEGER, &val, sizeof(int));
  }

  void operator()(double &val)
  {
    ModifyValue(TYPE_DOUBLE, &val, sizeof(double));
  }

  void operator()(std::string &val)
  {
    char buffer[128];
    strncpy(buffer, val.c_str(), 127);
    ModifyValue(TYPE_STRING, buffer, 128);
    val = buffer;
  }
};

MyVariant GetAValueFromC()
{
  char buffer[128];
  int type = GetAValue(buffer, 128);

  switch(type)
  {
  case TYPE_INTEGER:
    return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer[0]);
  case TYPE_DOUBLE:
    return *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&buffer[0]);
  case TYPE_STRING:
    return std::string(buffer);
  }
}

int main()
{
  MyVariant value = GetAValueFromC();
  //Non-modifying
  boost::apply_visitor(DoSomethingWithValueVisit(), value);
  //Modifying
  boost::apply_visitor(ModifyValueVisit(), value);
}
```

Feel free to add more types to the variant as needed.

Answer (score 5):

> that can be passed to functions written in the C language

No respectable variant in C++ is C-compatible, beyond passing a pointer to it as void* and providing functions that might manipulate it. C variants are guaranteed to be non-type-safe, whereas C++ variants have their types guaranteed. All you can do is store a type enumeration and a block of memory corresponding to the maximum size.

Also, `boost::any` isn't more heavyweight than a `vector`. You're just re-implementing it. In a less efficient way. And less safely.

Comment: std::vector may be heavyweight but I know how to pass its memory to C functions. I just don't know how I can do that with boost::any

Comment: @kristofa: Even if you pass the memory to C functions, how are you going to manipulate the contents!?

Comment: @krisostofa: Perhaps you should tell us about the C functions you are intended to pass arbitrary memory to. What do they normally take as parameters?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The C functions take a pointer to a buffer and buffer length

Comment: @krisostofa: But what's _contained_ in the buffer? What does the C function do with it? How does it interpret the data?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The buffer could hold a value of any type ( int, float, char etc ) or could be memory block where the C function will write a value of any type. You tell the C function what type is contained in the buffer.

Comment: @krisostofa: What do you mean by "any type"? Any basic type? Can it be an array of basic types? What are the possibilities here?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas OK. These types: char*, int, long, double, float and array of any of these types

Answer (score 1):

Serializing to the textual representation of the data into dynamically allocated memory can hardly be considered *minimal overhead*. And then again, regarding the C functions, what exactly do you want to pass the variant to the C functions for, do you want just to pass the variant through? do you intend on using the data inside the C functions?

If you only want to pass the variant through C code (but not use it there), then consider using boost::variant or boost::any and passing `void*`, if you intend on using the data inside C, I would recommend to use a structure with a tag to identify the type and an array big enough to hold the data you want to store and then cast the values into that array.

Comment: The C functions take a pointer to a buffer and buffer length. They will read and write to the buffer that I pass.

Comment: @krisostofa: You are still not providing the whole information: What does it mean to read and write from the buffer? Is a particular format required? Is it just serialization to save to disk/send over the network?

Comment: @dribeas These are database API functions like ODBC and OCI